# Input to reshape is a tensor with 10240 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 7500

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am writing code for a dual encoder model. I am stuck in a problem and don't know how to solve it.

The problem says that there could be a problem with local vision encoder.

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-f20ae5fb18a3> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import math
----> 2 history = dual_encoder.fit(
      3     train_dataset,
      4     epochs=num_epochs,
      5     validation_data=valid_dataset,

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52   try:
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'dual_encoder_4/local_vision_encoder/tf.reshape_10/Reshape' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/colab_kernel_launcher.py", line 37, in <module>
      ColabKernelApp.launch_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-34-f20ae5fb18a3>", line 2, in <cell line: 2>
      history = dual_encoder.fit(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "<ipython-input-32-81677a2df087>", line 92, in train_step
      impression_embeddings, finding_embeddings, image_embeddings = self(features, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "<ipython-input-23-5899b5db6d2f>", line 30, in call
      local_embeddings = self.local_vision_encoder(features["image"], training=training)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 451, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/tf_op_layer.py", line 226, in _call_wrapper
      return self._call_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/tf_op_layer.py", line 261, in _call_wrapper
      result = self.function(*args, **kwargs)
Node: 'dual_encoder_4/local_vision_encoder/tf.reshape_10/Reshape'
Input to reshape is a tensor with 10240 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 7500
     [[{{node dual_encoder_4/local_vision_encoder/tf.reshape_10/Reshape}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_608600]
```

Complete code along with printed shapes is below.

```
def create_global_vision_encoder(
    num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate, trainable=False
):
    # Load the pre-trained Xception model for global features.
    xception = keras.applications.Xception(
        include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
    )
    # Set the trainability of the base encoder.
    for layer in xception.layers:
        layer.trainable = trainable
    # Receive the images as inputs.
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="global_image_input")
    # Preprocess the input image.
    xception_input = tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input(inputs)
    # Generate the embeddings for the images using the xception model.
    embeddings = xception(xception_input)

    print(("Full image embeddings shape:", embeddings.shape))
    # Project the embeddings produced by the model.
    outputs = project_embeddings(
        embeddings, num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate
    )
    print("OOOutput embeddings GGlobal: ", outputs.shape)
    # Create the global vision encoder model.
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="global_vision_encoder")

CROP_SIZE = (50, 50)
BATCH_SIZE = 1


def create_local_vision_encoder(
    num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate, trainable=False
):
    # Load the pre-trained Xception model for local features.
    xception = keras.applications.Xception(
        include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
    )

    # Set the trainability of the base encoder.
    for layer in xception.layers:
        layer.trainable = trainable

    # Receive the embeddings as inputs.
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="local_image_input")

    # Extract local patches from the input image.
    patches = ImagePatchesAndEmbedding(CROP_SIZE, num_boxes=5, maxval=BATCH_SIZE)(inputs)
    print("Patches shape:", patches.shape)

    # Reshape the patches to match the expected input shape of Xception.
    patches_reshaped = tf.reshape(patches, (-1, CROP_SIZE[0], CROP_SIZE[1], 3))
    print("Reshaped patches shape:", patches_reshaped.shape)

    # Generate the embeddings for the reshaped patches using the Xception model.
    embeddings = xception(patches_reshaped)
    print("Embeddings shape:", embeddings.shape)
    
    embeddings_shape = embeddings.shape.as_list()

    #num_elements = tf.shape(embeddings)[1] * 5
    num_elements = embeddings_shape[1]

    target_size = math.ceil(num_elements / 7500) * 7500

# Reshape the embeddings back to the original shape with the target size
    embeddings_reshaped = tf.reshape(embeddings, (-1, target_size))

    #embeddings_reshaped = tf.reshape(embeddings, (-1, num_elements))

    # Reshape the embeddings back to the original shape.
    #embeddings_reshaped = tf.reshape(embeddings, (tf.shape(embeddings)[0], -1))
    #embeddings_reshaped = tf.reshape(embeddings, (-1, 5 * embeddings.shape[-1]))
    print("Reshaped embeddings shape:", embeddings_reshaped.shape)

    # Project the reshaped embeddings.
    outputs = project_embeddings(
        embeddings_reshaped, num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate
    )
    print("OOutput embeddings LLLocal: ", outputs.shape)
    # Create the local vision encoder model.
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="local_vision_encoder")



def create_impression_encoder(
    num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate, trainable=False
):
    # Load the BERT preprocessing module for impressions.
    preprocess = hub.KerasLayer(
        "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/2",
        name="impression_preprocessing",
    )
    # Load the pre-trained BERT model for impressions.
    bert = hub.KerasLayer(
        "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8/1",
        name="impression_bert",
    )
    # Set the trainability of the base encoder.
    bert.trainable = trainable
    # Receive the impressions as inputs.
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name="impression_input")
    # Preprocess the impressions.
    bert_inputs = preprocess(inputs)
    # Generate embeddings for the preprocessed impressions using the BERT model.
    embeddings = bert(bert_inputs)["sequence_output"]
    # Project the embeddings produced by the model.
    outputs = project_embeddings(
        embeddings, num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate
    )
    print("OOOutput embeddings IImpression: ", outputs.shape)
    # Create the impression encoder model.
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="impression_encoder")

def create_finding_encoder(
    num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate, trainable=False
):
    # Load the BERT preprocessing module for findings.
    finding_preprocessing = hub.KerasLayer(
        "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/2",
        name="finding_preprocessing",
    )
    # Load the pre-trained BERT model for findings.
    finding_bert = hub.KerasLayer(
        "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8/1",
        name="finding_bert",
    )
    # Set the trainability of the base encoder.
    finding_bert.trainable = trainable
    # Receive the findings as inputs.
    finding_input = layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name="finding_input")
    # Preprocess the findings.
    finding_processed = finding_preprocessing(finding_input)
    # Generate embeddings for the preprocessed findings using the BERT model.
    finding_embeddings = finding_bert(finding_processed)["sequence_output"]
    # Project the embeddings produced by the model.
    finding_outputs = project_embeddings(
        finding_embeddings, num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate
    )
    print("OOOutput embeddings FFinding: ", finding_outputs.shape)
    # Create the finding encoder model.
    return keras.Model(finding_input, finding_outputs, name="finding_encoder")
```

Shapes for the above part is printed below, these shapes can be identified in the code lines above.

```
('Full image embeddings shape:', TensorShape([None, 2048]))
OOOutput embeddings GGlobal:  (None, 300)
Patches shape: (None, 5, 2048)
Reshaped patches shape: (None, 50, 50, 3)
Embeddings shape: (None, 2048)
Reshaped embeddings shape: (None, 7500)
OOutput embeddings LLLocal:  (None, 300)
OOOutput embeddings IImpression:  (None, 128, 300)
OOOutput embeddings FFinding:  (None, 128, 300)
Number of GPUs: 0
Number of examples (image-impression-finding pairs): 100
Batch size: 1
Steps per epoch: 100
```

further code is below, which does not to be incorrect as the problem seems to be in local vision encoder which generates patches.

```
class DualEncoder(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, impression_encoder, finding_encoder, global_vision_encoder, local_vision_encoder, temperature=1.0, **kwargs):
        super(DualEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.impression_encoder = impression_encoder
        self.finding_encoder = finding_encoder
        self.global_vision_encoder = global_vision_encoder
        self.local_vision_encoder = local_vision_encoder
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")
        self.image_projection = layers.Dense(300)  # Add a projection layer for image embeddings

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.loss_tracker]

def call(self, features, training=False):
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        # Get the embeddings for the impressions.
        impression_embeddings = self.impression_encoder(features["impression"], training=training)
        # Get the embeddings for the findings.
        finding_embeddings = self.finding_encoder(features["finding"], training=training)
        text_embeddings = tf.concat([impression_embeddings, finding_embeddings], axis=1)
        print("Text Embeddings Shape is", text_embeddings.shape)


    with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
        # Get the global embeddings for the images.
        global_embeddings = self.global_vision_encoder(features["image"], training=training)
        # Get the local embeddings for the images.
        local_embeddings = self.local_vision_encoder(features["image"], training=training)
        # Concatenate the global and local embeddings.
        image_embeddings = tf.concat([global_embeddings, local_embeddings], axis=1)
        print("Image embeddings shape:", image_embeddings.shape)
    return impression_embeddings, finding_embeddings, image_embeddings

def compute_loss(self, impression_embeddings, finding_embeddings, image_embeddings):
    # Concatenate the impression and finding embeddings
    text_embeddings = tf.concat([impression_embeddings, finding_embeddings], axis=1)
    print("Text Embeddings Shape is", text_embeddings.shape)

    # Reshape text embeddings to have the same number of dimensions as image embeddings
    #text_embeddings_reshaped = tf.reshape(text_embeddings, [-1, text_embeddings.shape[-1]])
    text_embeddings_reshaped = tf.reshape(text_embeddings, [-1, image_embeddings.shape[-1]])
    print("Text Embeddings Reshaped Shape is", text_embeddings_reshaped.shape)

    # Compute the dot product between reshaped text embeddings and image embeddings
    logits = tf.matmul(text_embeddings_reshaped, image_embeddings, transpose_b=True) / self.temperature
    logits_reshaped = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 256, 256])
    #logits_reshaped = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 7500])
    #logits = tf.matmul(text_embeddings_reshaped, image_embeddings, transpose_b=True) / self.temperature
    print("Logits Shape is", logits.shape)
    print("Logits Shape is", logits_reshaped.shape)
    # Reshape logits to match the shape of text embeddings
    images_similarity = tf.matmul(image_embeddings, image_embeddings, transpose_b=True)
    print("Images similarity Shape is", images_similarity.shape)
    captions_similarity = tf.matmul(text_embeddings, text_embeddings, transpose_b=True)
    print("Captions similarity Shape is", captions_similarity.shape)
    targets = keras.activations.softmax((captions_similarity + images_similarity) / (2 * self.temperature))
    print("Targets Shape is", targets.shape)

    # Compute the loss for the captions using cross-entropy
    captions_loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(targets, logits_reshaped)
    #captions_loss = 1 - tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(targets, tf.transpose(logits))
    images_loss = 1 - tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(tf.transpose(targets), logits_reshaped)
    # Return the mean of the loss over the batch.
    return (tf.reduce_mean(captions_loss) + tf.reduce_mean(images_loss)) / 2


def train_step(self, features):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # Forward pass
    impression_embeddings, finding_embeddings, image_embeddings = self(features, training=True)
    tf.print("Batch size:", tf.shape(impression_embeddings)[0])
    tf.print("Impression embeddings shape:", tf.shape(impression_embeddings))
    tf.print("Finding embeddings shape:", tf.shape(finding_embeddings))
    tf.print("Image embeddings shape:", tf.shape(image_embeddings))
    loss = self.compute_loss(impression_embeddings, finding_embeddings, image_embeddings)
    # Backward pass
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))
    # Monitor loss
    self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
    return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result()}

def test_step(self, features):
    impression_embeddings, finding_embeddings, image_embeddings = self(features, training=False)
    loss = self.compute_loss(impression_embeddings, finding_embeddings, image_embeddings)
    self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
    return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result()}
```